# Docker setup for PHP & Mysql which use PDO database connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, docker-compose

I have tried creating a docker container with PHP, Apache & Mysql with PHP Docker preconfigured installation for PDO services (pdo pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql). There was no problem running the docker the problem is when I tried connecting to the database using PDO.

```
<?php
   new PDO('db:host=db;dbname=glms','glms','glms')
```

This simple code will return an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in /var/www/../htdocs/index.php:.. Stack trace: #0 /var/www/../htdocs/index.php(18): PDO->__construct('db:host=db;dbna...', '..', '..') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/../htdocs/index.php on line ...
```

Already tried:

- enabling pdo service in the php.ini
- restarting apache service "service apache restart"

For docker setup:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.2"

services:
    php:
        build: './php/'
        volumes:
            - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}/:/var/www/gronia/
            - ./php/php7.1.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    apache:
        build: './apache/'
        depends_on:
            - php
            - db
        ports:
            - "8801:80"
        volumes:
            - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}/:/var/www/gronia/
    db:
        image: mysql:${MYSQL_VERSION}
        volumes:
            - "${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}/mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
            - "${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            - TZ=UTC
        command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']
    phpmyadmin:
        build: './phpmyadmin/'
        environment:
          - PMA_HOST=mysql
          - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
        depends_on:
            - "db"
        ports:
            - 89:80
```

PHP Docker

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine

RUN set -ex \
    && apk --no-cache add postgresql-libs postgresql-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pgsql pdo pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-enable pgsql pdo pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql
```

Mysql Docker (MYSQL_VERSION=5.7)

```
ARG MYSQL_VERSION
FROM mysql:${MYSQL_VERSION}

LABEL maintainer="Mahmoud Zalt <mahmoud@zalt.me>"

#####################################
# Set Timezone
#####################################

ARG TZ=UTC
ENV TZ ${TZ}
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone && chown -R mysql:root /var/lib/mysql/

COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf

CMD ["mysqld"]

EXPOSE 3306
```

All I need is a running PHP(v7.1) & Mysql(v5.7) with a tested PDO connection "new PDO('..;host=..;', '..', '..')".
If anyone can provide me the docker-compose.yml, PHP Docker, Mysql Docker Setup it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the connection be `"mysql:host=db;dbname=db"`

Comment: flip, that solve it, thank you very much  